# Win32 Toolbar Dropdown Button Message Handling

Tags: c++, winapi, notifications, message

I have a toolbar to a window in my application. I have read  [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  and can handle command and notification messages. My problem is with a dropdown menu attached to a button on the toolbar. The menu items open modal dialog boxes and wait for user to finalize settings changes. After the user clicks 'ok' or 'cancel' focus returns to the main window, however, the toolbar is still under the impression that the left mouse button is down so everytime i drag the mouse over the toolbar button that was clicked the button takes the 'button is checked' state and 'appears' to be pressed.

Is the problem related to the tracking of mouse events?

Here is notification message handling within window proc:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            LPNMHDR lpnm = ( ( LPNMHDR )lParam );
            LPNMTOOLBAR lpnmTB = ( ( LPNMTOOLBAR )lParam );

            switch( lpnm->code )
            {
            case TBN_DROPDOWN:
                {
                    // Get the coordinates of the button.
                    RECT rc;
                    SendMessage( lpnmTB->hdr.hwndFrom, TB_GETRECT, ( WPARAM )lpnmTB->iItem, ( LPARAM )&rc );

                    // Convert to screen coordinates.            
                    MapWindowPoints( lpnmTB->hdr.hwndFrom, HWND_DESKTOP, ( LPPOINT )&rc, 2 );                         

                    // handle dropdown menus
                    return HandleTexEditDropdown( hWnd, lpnmTB, rc );
                }
            default:
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
```

Here is handle TexEditDropdown():

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CWindowManager::HandleTexEditDropdown( HWND hWnd, LPNMTOOLBAR lpnm, RECT &rc )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    switch( lpnm->iItem )
    {
    case IDM_EDITTEXTURE_FILL:
        {
            // Get the menu.
            HMENU hMenuLoaded = LoadMenu( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDR_BUCKETFILL ) ); 

            // Get the submenu for the first menu item.
            HMENU hPopupMenu = GetSubMenu( hMenuLoaded, 0 );

            // Set up the pop-up menu.
            // In case the toolbar is too close to the bottom of the screen, 
            // set rcExclude equal to the button rectangle and the menu will appear above 
            // the button, and not below it.
            TPMPARAMS tpm;

            tpm.cbSize    = sizeof( TPMPARAMS );
            tpm.rcExclude = rc;

            // Show the menu and wait for input. 
            // If the user selects an item, its WM_COMMAND is sent.

            INT nCmd = TrackPopupMenuEx( hPopupMenu, 
                TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_VERTICAL | TPM_RETURNCMD, 
                rc.left, rc.bottom, hWnd, &tpm );

            DestroyMenu( hMenuLoaded );
            switch( nCmd )
            {
            case IDM_BUCKETFILLSETTINGS:
                DialogBox( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), 
                    MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_TEXEDITBUCKETFILL ), 
                    hWnd, 
                    ( DLGPROC )TexEditSettingsProc );
                break;
            default:
                return 0;
            }

            SendMessage( ( HWND )lpnm->hdr.hwndFrom, TB_MARKBUTTON, lpnm->iItem, MAKELPARAM( FALSE, 0 ) );
            UpdateWindow( hWnd );
            SetStateChange();
            return 1;
        }
    case IDM_EDITTEXTURE_RECOVER:
        {
            // Get the menu.
            HMENU hMenuLoaded = LoadMenu( GetModuleHandle( NULL ), MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDR_RECOVER ) ); 

            // Get the submenu for the first menu item.
            HMENU hPopupMenu = GetSubMenu( hMenuLoaded, 0 );

            // Set up the pop-up menu.
            // In case the toolbar is too close to the bottom of the screen, 
            // set rcExclude equal to the button rectangle and the menu will appear above 
            // the button, and not below it.
            TPMPARAMS tpm;

            tpm.cbSize    = sizeof( TPMPARAMS );
            tpm.rcExclude = rc;

            // Show the menu and wait for input. 
            // If the user selects an item, its WM_COMMAND is sent.

            INT nCmd = TrackPopupMenuEx( hPopupMenu, 
                TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_VERTICAL | TPM_RETURNCMD, 
                rc.left, rc.bottom, hWnd, &tpm );

            DestroyMenu( hMenuLoaded );

            switch( nCmd )
            {
            case IDM_RECOVERFILE:
                {
                    WCHAR wcs[ MAX_PATH ] = L"",
                        wcsFiletype[ MAX_PATH ] = L"",
                        wcsFilename[ MAX_PATH ] = L"";
                    D3DXIMAGE_INFO info;

                    // get currently loaded image info
                    if( FAILED( hr = CTextureEditor::GetImageInfo( &info ) ) )
                    {
                        DebugStringDX( ClassName, "Failed to CTextureEditor::GetImageInfo() at AuxiliaryViewportProcess()", __LINE__, hr );
                        break;
                    }

                    if( !CTextureEditor::CatImageFileType( info.ImageFileFormat, wcsFiletype ) )
                    {
                        DebugStringDX( ClassName, "Invalid image filetype at AuxiliaryViewportProcess()", __LINE__, hr );
                        break;
                    }

                    wsprintf( wcs, L"GDEImage Filetype (*%s)", wcsFiletype );
                    memcpy( &wcs[ 26 ], L"*", sizeof( WCHAR ) );
                    memcpy( &wcs[ 27 ], wcsFiletype, 4 * sizeof( WCHAR ) );

                    // Declare and initialize an OPENFILENAME struct to use for OpenFile Dialog
                    OPENFILENAME ofn;
                    ZeroMemory( ( void* )&ofn, sizeof( OPENFILENAME ) );

                    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof( ofn ); // SEE NOTE BELOW
                    ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
                    ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Recover Image From File";
                    ofn.lpstrFilter = wcs;
                    ofn.lpstrFile = wcsFilename;
                    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
                    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
                    ofn.lpstrDefExt = L"image file";
                    ofn.lpstrInitialDir = app.GetBinDirectory();

                    // OpenFile Dialog
                    if( GetOpenFileName( &ofn ) )
                    {                                       
                        if( FAILED( hr = CTextureEditor::Recover( 0, wcsFilename ) ) )
                        {
                            DebugStringDX( ClassName, "Failed to CTextureEditor::Recover() at AuxiliaryViewportProc()", __LINE__, hr );
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            default:
                return 0;
            }

            SendMessage( ( HWND )lpnm->hdr.hwndFrom, TB_MARKBUTTON, lpnm->iItem, MAKELPARAM( FALSE, 0 ) );
            UpdateWindow( hWnd );
            SetStateChange();
            return 1;
        }
    default:
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the returned value for [TBN_DROPDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not correct -- you are returning `1` which maps to `TBDDRET_NODEFAULT` meaning "The drop-down was not handled", you'll need to return `TBDDRET_DEFAULT` or `TBDDRET_TREATPRESSED`.